# Store many numbers as a single unique number

Tags: php, numbers, primes, bitmask

I have the necessity to store many numbers (i can decide which numbers) as a single unique number from which i should be able to retrieve the original number.
I already know 2 ways to do this:

1) Fundamental theorem of arithmetic (Prime Numbers)
Say i have 5 values, i assign a prime number other than 1 to each value

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 5
d = 7
e = 13
```

If i want to store a, b and c i can multiply them `2*3*5=30` and i know no other product of primes can be 30. Then to check if a value contains, for example, b, all i need to do is `30 % b == 0`

2) Bitmask 
Just like Linux permissions, use powers of 2 and sum each value

But these 2 methods grow up fast (1st way faster than 2nd), and using prime numbers requires me to have a lot of primes.
Is there any other method to do this efficiently when you have, for example, a thousand values?

Comment: Do you have some more background on this question? In general it cannot be done more efficient than the bitmasking option, since in your example you would have `2^5` possibilities, which require 5 bits to be able to store all of them. But I'm curious as to where the need to store it in a single number arises.

Comment: I need to send permissions through a JWT (JSON Web Token) and since i can get even hundreds of permissions for the same user (big application), i wanted to know if there was some way to write them in a compact way to avoid sending big tokens. By default i get them as an array of permission names, so i was thinking about alternatives, an array of ids is already better, but i was wondering if there were even better ways. I'll probably end up just removing permissions from the token if it can't get better than 64 bits

Comment: I'm not familiar with JWT, but for hundreds of permissions you would only need hundreds of bits, which might not be a lot? Perhaps you can find a different way to store the bits (e.g. multiple 64ints) and get a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing, say, base 10 numbers, then do a conversion through base 11 numbers.  With the increased base, you have an extra 'digit'.  Use that digit as a separator.  So, three base 10 numbers "10, 42, 457" become "10A42A457": a single base 11 number (with 'A' as the additional digit).

Whatever base your original numbers are in, increase the base by 1 and concatenate, using the extra digit as a separator.  That will give you a single number in the increased base.

That single number can be stored in whatever number base you find convenient: binary, denary or hex for example.

To retrieve your original numbers just convert to base 11 (or whatever) and replace the extra digit with separators.

ETA: You don't have to use base 11.  The single number "10A42A457" is also a valid hexadecimal number, so any base of 11 or above could be used.  Hex may be easier to work with than base 11.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other method to do this efficiently when you have, for example, a **thousand values?**

I an not a mathematician but it's basic math, **all depends on range**

**Range 0-1:** You want to store 4 numbers 0-1 - it's basically binary system

```
Number1 + Number2 * 2^1 + Number3 * 2^2 + Number4 * 2^3
```

**Range 0-50** You want to store 4 numbers 0-49

```
Number1 + Number2 * 50^1 + Number3 * 50^2 + Number4 * 50^3
```

**Range 0-X** You want to store N numbers 0-X

```
Number1 + Number2 * (X+1)^1 + Number3 * (X+1)^2 + ... + NumberN * (X+1)^(N-1)
```

**If you have no pattern for your numbers (so it can get compressed in some way) there is really no other way.**

It's also super easy for computer to resolve the number unlike the prime numbers

---

## Predetermined values

@FlorainK comment pointed me to fact I missed

> (i can decide which numbers)

The only logical solution is give your numbers references

```
0 is 15342
1 is 6547
2 is 76234
3 is "i like stack overflow"
4 is 42141
```

so you'll work range `0-4` (5 options) and whatever combination  length. Use reference when "encoding" and "decoding" the number

> a thousand values?

**so you'll work with Range 0-999**

```
0 is 62342
1 is 7456345653
2 is 45656234532
...
998 is 7623452
999 is 4324234326453
```

Let's say you use 64-bit system and programming/db language that works with 64-bit integers

```
2^64 = 18446744073709551616
```

your max range is `1000^X < 18446744073709551616` where `X` is number of numbers you can store in one single 64-bit integer number

**Which is only 6.**

**You can store only 6 separate numbers 0-999 that will fit one 64-bit integer number.**

```
0,0,0,0,0,0 is 0
1,0,0,0,0,0 is 1
0,1,0,0,0,0 is 1000
999,999,999,999,999,999 is ~1e+18
```

Comment: The question states that he can decide which values will be possible to store. Suppose he wants to know of the four number 2, 6, 12, 49 which are present, then he could encode that information with 4 bits (together with the mapping from each bit to each value). Which is much more efficient than the solution proposed in this answer.

Comment: I think your solution is most efficient if values can occur multiple times, for instance if we would have to store the [76234, 87345, 76234]. However, if no multiples can occur I think 5 bits is more efficient. The example solutions @valepu gives seem to indicate that repeated values will not occur, since his solutions do not cater for them.

Comment: @FlorianK i edited answer a bit, read it and think about it. He wants to store multiple [0-999] as one digit. I don't think about any other solution.

Comment: In a 64 bit integer he can store for 64 predetermined numbers whether they are in the set or not (1st bit indicates whether first number is present, 2nd bit second number etc.). This is the bitmasking solution he referred to in the original post, where for 3 "numbers" (in this case read, write and execute) it is stored in 3 bits whether each of them is present.

Comment: @FlorianK Ok i see your point he wants to store "a,b,c" and sometimes "a,b,c,d"

Comment: @Peter yes, sorry if i haven't been clear, what i meant is i have "a, b, c, d e" then i want to store, let's say in a database, "a b c" in a row, "a b c d" in another and "a d e" in another using a single integer, and i don't want those integer to grow up too much, hitting a value higher than "max integer", if i have something around 1000 values

Comment: @FlorianK  i added other ansawer

Comment: @valepu you have two answers you can use, i don't see an option for you for 1000 values. if you use database just use 1:many relationship instead that huge huge magic

Comment: I was wondering if there's some other "math trick" (let's call it that) like the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic but with simpler numbers and operations that gives me unique numbers from which i can retrieve one of the original numbers back. If there's not i will accept your other answer. I'm not storing them in a database as you wrote, though, it was just an example. You can see why i'm looking for this in a comment under the question

Comment: @valepu I gave you two answers - how to store N numbers 0-999, how to store combination of N falgs. Everything else is compression where you need pattern. I answered your question assuming you have random numbers. You can't compress random.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you want to store "a,b,c" or "a,b" or "a,b,c,d" or "a" etc. (thanks @FlorianK)

in such case just could use bitwise operators and powers of two

```
$a = 1 << 0; // 1
$b = 1 << 1; // 2
$c = 1 << 2; // 4
$d = 1 << 3; // 8
.. etc
```

let's say `$flag` has `$a` and `$c`

```
$flag = $a | $c; // $flag is integer here
```

now check it

```
$ok = ($flag & $a) && ($flag & $c); // true
$ok = ($flag & $a) && ($flag & $b); // false
```

**so in 64 bit system/language/os you can use up to 64 flags which gives you a 2^64 combinations**

there is no really other option. prime numbers are much worse for this as you skip many numbers in-between while binary system uses every single number.

---

I see you are using database and you want to store this in DB.

I really think we are dealing here with [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should reconsider your application instead of making such workarounds.

Comment: Actually the prime number method wastes quite a lot of numbers. For instance, all multiple of fours would encode the situation where the permission encoded by 2 is in the set twice, which cannot happen. So that's already a quarter of the numbers that are wasted, but the same thing holds for multiples of 9 (3 * 3), etc.

Comment: @FlorianK of course you are right. 4 is 2 x 2, 8 is 2x2x2 etc. I said prime numbers are wasting numbers in original answer, then I had brain freeze and I edited my answer